# not able to see the data returned by database to edittext

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying view data view by unique id, I want use phone as unique id
I created following database code

```
public String getEmpName(String empphone) throws SQLException {
    String[] columns = new String[] { EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, EMP_DOB, EMP_ADDR, EMP_PHONE };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(EMPINFO_TABLE_NAME, columns, EMP_PHONE + "="
            + empphone, null, null, null, null, null);

    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(EMP_ID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(EMP_NAME);
    int iADDR = c.getColumnIndex(EMP_ADDR);
    int iPHONE = c.getColumnIndex(EMP_PHONE);
    int iDOB = c.getColumnIndex(EMP_DOB);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName)
                + " " + c.getString(iADDR)+ " " + c.getString(iPHONE)+ " " + c.getString(iDOB)
                + "\n";

    }
    return result;
}
```

#### employee class

```
public void onClick(View view){

    String empname=nameedittext.getText().toString();
    String empdateofbirth=dateedittext.getText().toString();
    String empaddress=addressedittext.getText().toString();
    String empphone=phoneedittext.getText().toString();

    dbhandle=new DBhandle(this);
    dbhandle=dbhandle.open();

    String data=dbhandle.getEmpName(empphone);
    nameedittext.setText(data);
 }
```

The problem is that when click the button i am able to get the data uniquely but whole data is shown in same edittext ie nameedittext but i want is that phone number should be seen in **phoneedittext**, name should be seen on **nameedittext** and so on

Comment: Which part *exactly* are you currently stuck on? There are many ways to do it

Comment: What exactly is your question, how to read the data(name, phone number etch) or how to show them on the editText?

Comment: Will the `getEmpName()` method always just return one row in the database?

Comment: @codeMagic i want to set the data returned to respective edittexts i.e phone number should be seen in phoneedittext, name should be seen on nameedittext and so on

Comment: @SkarosIlias how to show them on the editText?

Comment: I know *what* you are trying to do. What I asked is what part are you stuck on? Getting the data from the result variable, setting text, ???

Comment: It looks like you are duplicating the phone number in both `KEY_ROWID` and `EMP_PHONE `, there is no reason to do that.

Comment: `textView.setText("someString");`

Comment: Why are you putting them in one variable? Why not create a class to hold the data, create an instance and set the values appropriately. Then, after calling that method you can call a method to retrieve the instance data and set it appropriately. Again, there are many ways but you aren't asking a specific question

Comment: @codeMagic setting text

Comment: Just like Skaros showed a couple comments above

Comment: @codeMagic now i think have more specific problem, i just edited my query, problem is descibed at the end

Comment: That is a little more clear where your problem is. I hope my answer can help but it assumes you know basic Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but whole data is shown in same edittext

Yes, because you are saving it all in one String variable and setting that String to one `EditText`. I'm not sure why you would expect anything different.

You would need to parse each one out of that `String`. I would suggest creating a class, maybe `Person.java`. In there, you would have attributes of the data you are getting from the db. So in your `getEmpName()` function, you would create an instance of the `Person` class and set the attributes accordingly instead of saving them all to a single `String` variable.

Then you can call a method at the end of `getEmpName()` to set each `EditText` with that instance you created.

**Alternatively,**

You could do something like a [HashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html) and save each one in there and pull them out to set in your `EditText`s.